# Simple math in Script

Tags: script, math

I want to create a script that takes 3 numbers and verifies that:

1. Each of the numbers is less than 8.
2. The sum of the numbers is 15.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the smallest script I could come up with, at 13 opcodes:

```
OP_3DUP
OP_ADD
OP_ADD
OP_15 OP_NUMEQUALVERIFY
OP_8 OP_LESSTHAN OP_VERIFY
OP_8 OP_LESSTHAN OP_VERIFY
OP_8 OP_LESSTHAN
```

It saves some bytes by using `OP_3DUP` to duplicate all three input numbers, and one byte by checking the addition first using `OP_NUMEQUALVERIFY` instead of `OP_NUMEQUAL`, which saves one `OP_VERIFY` opcode.

Comment: Nice, that's a lot simpler indeed.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the shortest approach for this question.

Answer (score 3):

```
OP_DUP OP_8 OP_LESSTHAN OP_VERIFY
OP_SWAP OP_DUP OP_8 OP_LESSTHAN OP_VERIFY
OP_ROT OP_DUP OP_8 OP_LESSTHAN OP_VERIFY
OP_ADD OP_ADD OP_15 OP_NUMEQUAL
```

Tracing the execution (for a successful input):

- Initial: *a b c*
- `OP_DUP`: *a b c c*
- `OP_8`: *a b c c 8*
- `OP_LESSTHAN`: *a b c 1*
- `OP_VERIFY`: *a b c*
- `OP_SWAP`: *a c b*
- `OP_DUP`: *a c b b*
- `OP_8`: *a c b b 8*
- `OP_LESSTHAN`: *a c b 1*
- `OP_VERIFY`: *a c b*
- `OP_ROT`: *c b a*
- `OP_DUP`: *c b a a*
- `OP_8`: *c b a a 8*
- `OP_LESSTHAN`: *c b a 1*
- `OP_VERIFY`: *c b a*
- `OP_ADD`: *c (a+b)*
- `OP_ADD`: *(a+b+c)*
- `OP_15`: *(a+b+c) 15*
- `OP_NUMEQUAL`: *1*

Comment: Wouldn't OP_PICK be simpler than duplicating and swapping/rotating?

Comment: I think it'd require the same number of opcodes and bytes, but feel free to suggest as an alternative.

Comment: No need, just making sure I haven't missed something obvious. I'm not particularly versed in Script.